# Stack circle avatar on top of drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

How can I stack circle avatar on top of a drawer,
Something like this
[image]

So far I managed to make the drawer like that by wrapping it in a Padding widget

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 80, 0, 0),
      child: Drawer(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
```

How can I stack the circle avatar like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might help you

```
Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 80, 0, 0),
  child: Stack(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
    children: [
      Drawer(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: -40,
        right: 16,
        child: Container(
        width: 80,
         height: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),)
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: The circle gets cropped on the upper boundary

Comment: did you add the attribute `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` to the stack?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, It worked perfectly